# Node.js - How to link to local file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a basic script source link:

```
// index.html
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Which doesn't work, despite the file existing. I tried to link to it in the Node.js server but it threw an error that express wasn't defined, yet it is.

```
//server.js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var clientlist = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
    app.use(express().static('/js/jquery.js'));
});
```

Comment: have you set your public folder and added js there? e.g. `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` and make a folder js with jquery.js in it

Comment: Same thing, says express is not defined.

Comment: you are not defining `express` anywhere

Comment: I require it, and then use what the value of the definition would be, as you said I need to do: var express = express();

Comment: @TerryAnderson -- no `var express = express();` is wrong, and not what I said in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution.

#### Note:

You may want to replace '/var/www/nodeserver', with the directory, you are working in!

First of all, don't use `res.sendfile()`, it is deprecated, use `res.sendFile()` instead.
Or just serve a complete directory:

## Setting all up

### index.js

This could be your 'index.js' in '/var/www/nodeserver':

```
// Setup basic express server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// Change 3000 to whatever port, you want to access the site with"http://127.0.0.1:3000"
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Server listening at port "+port);
});

// Routing
var dir = __dirname+'/public'; // Path of the index.js but one dir further (public)
app.use(express.static(dir)); // serve all files in '/var/www/nodeserver/public/'
```

### package.json

And you would need to have a 'package.json', containing this:

```
{
    "name": "nameofyourapplication",
    "version": "versionofyourapplication",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.10.2",
        "socket.io": "^1.3.7"
    }
}
```

### Installation

Then install the dependencies defined in the 'package.json', with this command: `npm install`, while in the directory '/var/www/nodeserver/'.
This will install all the dependencies, locally, so it will create a folder named 'node_modules', in '/var/www/nodeserver'.

### Using it

Next you just need to put all the files you want to serve, into the 'public' folder in '/var/www/nodeserver' and run the 'index.js' with `node index.js`.

### The Filetree

Your filetree should then look something like this:

- nodeserver

  - node_modules

    - express
    - socket.io
  - public

    - js

      - jquery.js
  - index.js
  - package.json

That should do it!

Comment: This actually worked perfectly, I'm going to need to refresh it all a bit but other than that it's great, thanks!

Comment: Well if it now works @TerryAnderson, you may want to consider marking my Answer as the Solution! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your [requires are wrong](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html), and hence express is not defined

Chamnge your first line `var app = require('express');`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

Comment: If I change that it throws an error: TypeError: Cannot read property '_header' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Before your file name put __dirname,'index.html'.
New code will be res.sendfile(__dirname + 'index.html');

And also your first line is wrong it should be var express = require('express');